# Overloading on const and volatile- why does it work by reference?

Tags: c++, constants, overloading, volatile

I have the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void func(const int& a)
{
    std::cout << "func(const)" << std::endl;
}

void func(volatile int& a)
{
    std::cout << "func(volatile)" << std::endl;
}

void func(const volatile int& a)
{
    std::cout << "func(const volatile)" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const int a = 0;
    const volatile int b = 0;
    volatile int c = 0;
    func(a);
    func(b);
    func(c);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The above code shows overloading based on whether the parameters are const/volatile. However, if I were to change the parameters from `int&` to `int`, the code no longer compiles and I cannot overload based upon const/volatile parameter types. I dont get why we can overload based on const and volatile if the int is passed by reference, but not if its passed by value?

EDIT I should emphasise I understand what a reference does- I do not understand why a reference alias is allowed to overload on const but a normal int is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps it is useful to take a step back from the functions and just look at the use-cases themselves.

First, we will define an integer and a constant integer for use in our examples:

```
int       anInt     = 1;
const int aConstInt = 1;
```

Next, we take a look at what happens when using these variables to set the values of other integers and constant integers:

```
int       a = anInt;     // This works, we can set an int's value
                         //  using an int
int       b = aConstInt; // This works, we can set an int's value
                         //  using a const int
const int c = anInt;     // This works, we can set a const int's value
                         //  using an int
const int d = aConstInt; // This works, we can set a const int's value
                         //  using a const int
```

As you can see, there is no way to resolve which overload of a function to select based on behavior (a const int can be accepted by both an int and a const int, and likewise an int can be accepted by both an int and a const int).

Next, we shall take a look at what happens when pass the first set of variables to references:

```
int& a = anInt;     // This works because we are using a
                    //  non-constant reference to access a
                    //  non-constant variable.
int& b = aConstInt; // This will NOT work because we are
                    //  trying to access a constant
                    //  variable through a non-constant
                    //  reference (i.e. we could
                    //  potentially change a constant
                    //  variable through the non-const
                    //  reference).

const int& c = anInt;     // This works because we are using a
                          //  constant reference (i.e. "I cannot
                          //  try to change the referenced
                          //  variable using this reference") to
                          //  a non-constant variable.
const int& d = aConstInt; // This will work because we are trying
                          //  to access a constant variable 
                          //  through a constant reference.
```

As you can see, there is some useful behavior that can be had out of distinguishing between an int reference and a const int reference (i.e. disallowing creation of a non-constant reference when a constant reference type is expected).

Answer (score 13):

The issue is that the top level `const` and/or `volatile` are ignored in overload resolution. So

```
void foo(const int);
```

is exactly the same as

```
void foo(int);
```

and similarly for `volatile`. This is a language rule, and it makes sense since the arguments are passed by value. On the other hand, reference to `const/volatile` or pointer to `const/volatile` have a different meaning: you are not allowed to call non-const/volatile methods on what they refer to or point to. Here, the `const` `volatile` are not top level.

```
void foo(int& i);       // can modify what i refers to, and this has effects outside of foo.
void foo(const int& i); // cannot modify what i refers to
```

The two above declarations have very different semantics, so the language makes them distinct concerning overload resolution.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the difference between int& and int- I thought a reference is just an alias for another variable? So int& and int are no different? One just means the alias?

Comment: @user997112 When you use references, no copy is made. When you use plain pass-by-value, the argument is copied.

Comment: @user997112 I have tried to elaborate. In the reference case, the semantics are radically different. It is useful for the language to have separate overloads. Not to have them would be confusing.

Comment: @H2CO3 I know that- but I am simply asking "Why can a reference overload based on const?". I do not understand why reference/pointer is special? Actually I kinda understand why pointer because the pointer is a type itself?

Comment: @user997112 Yes, references are just aliases.  But a function that takes an alias to an existing `int` is not the same as a function that requests the caller create a copy of the `int` and hand it to the function.

Comment: @user997112 It is quite useful to allow the overload for references based on cv qualifiers. It is also very useful to do the same for pointers (where the cv qualification applies to the object they point to, not to the pointers themselves). It is not so useful for values. In the end, the language rules are made by humans, based on what they believe to be useful, implementable, and (at least in theory) easy to understand.

Comment: Ok so generally speaking, if I had my own class X, would I be able to do the above for references to X and not if X was by value?

Comment: @user997112 The same applies to user defined types as does to built-ins and enums.